# PostgreSQL ERROR:ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions

Tags: postgresql

while inserting into table getting error

myquery:

```
INSERT INTO ike.poledata(
             poleid, feature, value, others, users,  type)
    VALUES ( 'dba', 'dba1','dba2','dba3', 'dba4', 'dba4');
```

error:

> ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions LINE 1:
>   ...oledata (uid,poleid ,feature, value,others, users,type,opera...

QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO ike.hist_poledata (uid,poleid ,feature, value,others, users,type,operation,new_value)
VALUES (new.uid,new.poleid,new.feature,new.value,new.users,new.type)
```

> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function ike.hist_poledata() line 9 at SQL
>   statement
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions SQL state:
>   42601 Context: PL/pgSQL function ike.hist_poledata() line 9 at SQL
>   statement

please let me know the solution for this error.
 thanks in advance.

Comment: PostgreSQL <> MySQL <> SQL Server. I have removed all the irrelevant tags.

Comment: am using postgreql while  creating function got this error

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? You specified 9 columns in the `insert` list, but only 6 values in the `values()` part

Answer (score 2):

Your column list `INSERT INTO ike.hist_poledata (uid,poleid ,feature, value,others, users,type,operation,new_value)` has more column than the value list:

```
(new.uid,new.poleid,new.feature,new.value,new.users,new.type)
```

Remove unused columns or add the values for them

```
INSERT INTO ike.hist_poledata (uid,poleid ,feature, value,others, users,type)
                     values   (new.uid,new.poleid,new.feature,new.value,new.users,new.type)
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct below statement of 6 values to 9 as below:

```
INSERT INTO ike.hist_poledata (uid,poleid ,feature, value,others, users,type,operation,new_value)
VALUES (new.uid,new.poleid,new.feature,new.value,new.users,new.type)
```

Change to something like:

```
INSERT INTO ike.hist_poledata (uid,poleid ,feature, value,others, users,type,operation,new_value)
VALUES (new.uid,new.poleid,new.feature,new.value,new.others, new.users,new.type, new.operation, new.new_value)
```

The message clearly communicate about the request of update and supply of parameter mismatch.